# Laravel 8 Middleware in Production not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, production-environment, laravel-middleware

I created a middleware called "CheckForOriginSource.php" and added it to $middlewareGroups 'web'. This was created because we needed to track where people were coming from. It just looks for a query parameter in the url and adds it to a sesion that is used later.

CheckForOriginSource.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class CheckForOriginSource
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->query('origin')) {
            session(['origin' => $request->query('origin')]);
        } else {
            session(['origin' => 'Launchpad']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Kernel.php:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForOriginSource::class,
        ],
```

This all works fine locally, but when I pushed it to production it is not working.
When I log into the server and run php artisan route:list, it is not showing the middleware on any routes.
I tried `php artisan route:cache`, but unfortunately, the app has a closure on one of the routes it uses, so it will not cache it. I tried just clearing the route cache,
I have tried:

`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan clear-compiled`
`composer dump-autoload -o`
`php artisan optimize`

I have refreshed the server, checked for case errors for file name, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: it is not going to show that particular middleware, it will show you the group, `web` in this case ... how do you know the middleware is not working?